# How do you test a REPL/interactive shell that uses input() and infinite loop in python

Tags: python, shell

I created a custom REPL in python with the following code,

```
def repl():
   while True:
      try:
          line = input('$ ')
          do_stuff_with(line)
      except EOFError:
          print('bye bye')
          return
```

How can I test this function? I can't figure out how to simulate stdin (using StringIO), send some data, and then send a CTRL-D. Or a better question, what's a simple way to create a REPL that is testable. Note: I'm using python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several alternatives.

For driving interactive programs programmatically, use [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net), or [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

For testing, redefine `input()`.  Create a different function that is not interactive to drive the REPL through its tests, and insert it in the module where `repl()` is defined.  It will shadow the builtin `input()` and yours will be called instead.

Don't test `repl()`, test `do_stuff_with()` instead.